# How to highlight all instances of replaced text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to highlight all instances within a `div` that match a string of text. Here's the div:

```
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

I want the string `"Lorem ipsum"` to be highlighted twice, so I use this code:

```
let textCurrent = $("div").html().trim();
let text = "Lorem ipsum";
let newText = "Lorem ipsum";

textCurrent = textCurrent.replace(text, "<span class='highlight'>"+newText+"</span>");
$("div").html(textCurrent);
```

It highlights the first instance of "Lorem ipsum", but the problem is that it ONLY highlights the first instance of "Lorem ipsum", not both instances. When I replace the variables `text` and `newText` with the actual strings, like so:

```
textCurrent = textCurrent.replace(/'Lorem ipsum'/g, "<span class='highlight'>Lorem ipsum</span>");
$("div").html(textCurrent);
```

It works. But how do I highlight all instances while using variables such as `text` and `newText`?

https://jsfiddle.net/crduling/zmyxtd79/7/

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may do like:-

```js
$(function(){
  
let textCurrent = $("div").html().trim();
let text = "Lorem ipsum";
let newText = "Lorem ipsum";
let replaceText = "<span class='highlight'>"+newText+"</span>";
  
textCurrent = textCurrent.replace(new RegExp(text, 'g'), replaceText);

$("div").html(textCurrent);
  
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.html( function )](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) plus [new RegExp(pattern[, flags])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

where **g**: stands for global match; find all matches rather than stopping after the first match

The snippet:

```js
let text = "Lorem ipsum";
let newText = "Lorem ipsum";

$("div").html(function(i, str) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(text, 'g'), "<span class='highlight'>"+newText+"</span>");
});
```

```css
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

using only `javascript`

```js
const t = document.querySelector(".text");

t.innerHTML = t.innerText.replace(/ipsum/g, match => `<span class="red">${match}</span>`);
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
  eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```